# LevelDOWN could not locate the bindings file when using electron.js under Windows 7

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, node-gyp

I created nodeJS server that uses levelDOWN module. So when I'm starting my server with `node app.js` everything is fine. I want to create electron desktop app that will use my `app.js` file. So I installed electron module and created `electronApp.js` file:

```
    var app = require('electron').app;

    app.on('ready', function(){

        // start http server
        var server = require(__dirname + "/app");
    });
```

Now I'm trying to run my application `electron electronApp.js` but I'm getting next error:

[image]

I tried `node-gyp rebuild` and `electron-rebuild` as well but it did not help. I'm dissapointed. How to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same error and submitted an issue on Electron issue list: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8161

Hope this can be resolved soon.